# Real time database query

Tags: database

We have a windows program written in vbasic(i think) and we are re-writing the same program in c#. In the old program there is a grid. When we click any cell and as soon as edit the cell content the data in database is changing. In our new program we couldn't find the way of doing that. So we added some buttons for database actions like update selected cell.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in c# too.Use a datagridview and to bind with the database so that change in the grid effect database see [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database)

Answer (score 1):

Out of seeing dozens of legacy ODBC frontends put together in Access I would strongly advice *not to* commit changes in the database at real time. Instead try to create a lightweight process that helps the users to keep their data's quality high.

If you want this kind of functionality you could have the real time changes saved in a different schema, a set of different tables or with a flag that tells that these rows are unverified edits by the user X.

Rasel already gave you a pointer how to do the functionality in C#.